# NSButton setAlignment does not work

Tags: cocoa

I used

```
[button setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
```

to make the text display at the center of the button.

It worked.

But if I set button title attribute before the code, button 'setAlignment' will not work

```
- (void)setButtonTitle:(NSButton*)button fontName:(NSString*)fontName fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize fontColor:(NSColor*)fontColor;
{

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[button title]
                                     attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize]
                                                                            forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                              value:fontColor 
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [[button title] length] )];


    [button setAttributedTitle: attributedString];
    [button setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];//button title alignment always displayed as 'NSLeftTextAlignment' rather than 'NSCenterTextAlignment'.

}
```

title alignment always displayed as 'NSLeftTextAlignment' rather than 'NSCenterTextAlignment'.

Welcome any comment

Comment: Does it work if the title isn’t attributed? Maybe you need to set the alignment in the attributed string.

Comment: it worked if the title is not attributed, but I do not know how to add the alignment to the attributed string

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you’re using an attributed string for the button title, the attributes in that string are responsible for setting the alignment.

To centre that attributed string, add an `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` attribute with a centred alignment value:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *centredStyle = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[centredStyle setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];

NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:centredStyle,
                       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                       [NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize],
                       NSFontAttributeName,
                       fontColor,
                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                       nil];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[button title]
                                 attributes:attrs];

[button setAttributedTitle: attributedString];
```

In the code above, I’ve created a single `attrs` dictionary holding all the attributes for the attributed string. From your code, it looks like the font colour should be applied to the whole string anyway.

Comment: the answer is of course correct. I just want to express my frustration towards the manner in which things are designed in terms of ui development on the mac... I mean... so much code for having a button with a custom color centered text... it is freaking ridiculous. WAKE UP APPLE!!!