# Set text color and alignment in a NSButton with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, nsbutton

I am trying to change color to a NSButton, and I could do it using NSMutableDictionary, with this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande Bold" size:30.0];
[attrs setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[attrs setObject:[NSColor whiteColor]forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mystring attributes:attrs];
[myButton setAttributedTitle:attrStr];
```

it is working good but the problem is I don't know how to align the text to the center....
I tryed with

```
[attrs setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
```

but I get an error "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'setAlignment:'"...
Anyone can help please?
Thanks a lot,
Massy

Comment: You are invoking the method on the wrong object (dictionary does not support such method setAlignment). Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514157/nsbutton-setalignment-does-not-work

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for that....
You should write it as an answer so I can accept it...
Thanks again... Massy